# Unable to create AngularJS4 Project on Spring STS Eclipse - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/genuitec/eclipse/core/vU

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, spring-boot, eclipse-plugin

I am building a CRUD app using Spring STS and AngularJS 5, I have installed the Angular IDE 2017 CI 11b plugin. After restarting the IDE I am unable to create an AngularJS project and I get the following error. Thanks for the help.

I have attached the error logs below. Is there any other way where I can develop the Javascript part of the project and then integreate it with Spring Boot ?

## error.log

```
Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/genuitec/eclipse/core/vU
    at   com.genuitec.eclipse.modernweb.angular2.ui.project.NewAngular2ProjectWizard.init(NewAngular2ProjectWizard.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchWizardNode.getWizard(WorkbenchWizardNode.java:171)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardSelectionPage.getNextPage(WizardSelectionPage.java:107)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchWizardSelectionPage.getNextPage(WorkbenchWizardSelectionPage.java:97)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.NewWizardSelectionPage.advanceToNextPageOrFinish(NewWizardSelectionPage.java:71)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.NewWizardNewPage.lambda$0(NewWizardNewPage.java:348)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$1.run(StructuredViewer.java:831)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil.lambda$0(JFaceUtil.java:44)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireDoubleClick(StructuredViewer.java:828)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.handleDoubleSelect(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1459)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$4.widgetDefaultSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1258)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireDefaultSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:249)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$0(OpenStrategy.java:247)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:306)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:86)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4428)

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/genuitec/eclipse/core/vU
at com.genuitec.eclipse.modernweb.angular2.ui.project.NewAngular2ProjectWizard.init(NewAngular2ProjectWizard.java:68)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchWizardNode.getWizard(WorkbenchWizardNode.java:171)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardSelectionPage.getNextPage(WizardSelectionPage.java:107)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchWizardSelectionPage.getNextPage(WorkbenchWizardSelectionPage.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.nextPressed(WizardDialog.java:857)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:413)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.lambda$0(Dialog.java:619)
at org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener$1.widgetSelected(SelectionListener.java:81)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:249)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:86)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4428)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4238)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3817)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:818)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:794)
at org.eclipse.ui.actions.NewProjectAction.run(NewProjectAction.java:115)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:473)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:565)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:397)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:86)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4428)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4238)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3817)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1150)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1039)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:153)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:680)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)

com.genuitec.eclipse.core.GenuitecCoreRTException: Invalid thread state detected on save.
at com.genuitec.eclipse.core.F.C(Unknown Source)
at com.genuitec.eclipse.core.F$1.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
```

Comment: try to start STS from console/terminal with "-clean". It might solve your issue. I think you are talking about Angular 5 and not angularJs. Try Visual Studio IDE for angular and for integration put the files in static folder. You might find exact steps with some google.

Comment: launching STS -clean from console didn't work. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

Sambhav,

I'm sorry we missed your post - for faster support, please consider posting directly on our Angular IDE forum here: https://www.genuitec.com/forums/topics/webclipse/

From the stack trace you shared, it looks like you may have a corrupt installation, so I would recommend checking for an update, or re-installing Angular IDE. It *is* possible that something else is going wrong, though to asses that we'd need your entire error log (it's at [workspace_location]/.metadata/.log]) - if you could post that on our forums we could take a closer look.